# Jquery : Last image in array repeats twice, why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, function, setinterval

In my Array 'bg' the last item/image repeats twice when the function 'fadebg' gets to it,
can anybody answer me why is this happening and how to fix it?

```
var bg = [];
bg[0] = "resources/images/bg/1.jpg";
bg[1] = "resources/images/bg/2.jpg";
bg[2] = "resources/images/bg/3.jpg";
bg[3] = "resources/images/bg/4.jpg";
bg[4] = "resources/images/bg/5.jpg";
bg[5] = "resources/images/bg/6.jpg";
bg[6] = "resources/images/bg/7.jpg";
bg[7] = "resources/images/bg/8.jpg";
bg[8] = "resources/images/bg/9.jpg";
bg[9] = "resources/images/bg/10.jpg";

var i = 0;

setInterval(fadebg, 10000);

function fadebg() {
    if (i < 10) {
        $('#bg').css({ opacity: 0 });
        setTimeout(function () {
            $('#bg').attr('src', bg[i]).css({ opacity: 1 })
        }, 300);
    };
    if (i == 10) {
        i = -1;
        $('#bg').css({ opacity: 0 });
        setTimeout(function () {
            $('#bg').attr('src', bg[i]).css({ opacity: 1 })
        }, 300);
        };
    i++;
};
```

And by the way, does anybody know's a shorter version of this function 'fadebg'?

Comment: why you use this  `};` at closing brace of `if` ?

Comment: You could probably just use a `.each()` function instead of the if statement with an `i`

Comment: I've never seen anyone looping like that before ) TIL

Comment: how would it look whit a .each() function, can you post it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a simpler version:

```
(function() {
    var bgIndex = 0;
    setInterval(function() {
        var item = $('#bg').css({ opacity: 0 });
        setTimeout(function() {
            item.attr("src", bg[++bgIndex % bg.length]);
        }, 300);
    }, 10000);
})();
```

It uses the `%` trick to allow your index to cycle through the array without ever leaving the bounds of the array.

Also, this solves the original problem you had because the index variable is only incremented right when you go to use the index so there is no timing delay issue with when the variable is incremented and when it is used.

Summary of enhancements:

1. Use `% bl.length` trick to simplify code for staying within the bounds of the array and collapse your two branches of code to only one branch.
2. Increment array index only when we are just about to use it so there is no timing issue with when it's incremented.
3. Wrapped in IIFE so there are no globals.  The global `i` is a very dangerous practice.  One line of code that forgets the `var` in a `for (i = 0;...)` loop and now your global `i` gets trounced.
4. Saved value of `$('#bg')` so you're not regetting that a short time later.

Comment: Thanks! this worked for me. :)

var bgi = 0;

setInterval(function () {
    var bgitem = $('#bg');
    bgitem.css({ opacity: 0 });
    setTimeout(function () {
        bgitem.attr("src", bg[++bgi % bg.length]);
        bgitem.css({ opacity: 1 });
    }, 300);
}, 10000);

Answer (score 3):

It's because your functions inside `fadebg` close over the *variable* `i`, not the value it has as of when the function was created. They use the value it has when they *run*. This is the classic closure mistake. More: [*Closures are not complicated*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/closures-are-not-complicated.html).

To use the value as of when the function is *created*, you have to use something other than `i`. I usually use a builder function:

```
function buildTheCallback(src) {
    return function () {
        $('#bg').attr('src', src).css({ opacity: 1 })
    };
}
```

...which you use like this:

```
setTimeout(buildTheCallback(bg[i]), 300);
```

Now, the function we're giving `setTimeout` (which is the function returned by the call to `buildTheCallback` closes over the `src` argument we passed into it, which doesn't get changed.

---

Re a shorter version, something along these lines (<s>untested</s> *hey, what do you know, [it works](http://jsbin.com/naqesucu/1)* [I shortened the 10000ms to 1000ms for testing]):

```
(function() {
    var bg = [
        "resources/images/bg/1.jpg",
        "resources/images/bg/2.jpg",
        "resources/images/bg/3.jpg",
        "resources/images/bg/4.jpg",
        "resources/images/bg/5.jpg",
        "resources/images/bg/6.jpg",
        "resources/images/bg/7.jpg",
        "resources/images/bg/8.jpg",
        "resources/images/bg/9.jpg",
        "resources/images/bg/10.jpg"
        ];
    var bgIndex = -1;
    setInterval(fadeBg, 10000);

    function fadeBg() {
        bgIndex = (bgIndex + 1) % bg.length;
        $('#bg').css({ opacity: 0 });
        setTimeout(showBg, 300);
    }
    function showBg() {
        $('#bg').attr('src', bg[bgIndex]).css({ opacity: 1 })
    }
})();
```

*(I'm assuming that the real paths to the images aren't identical except for the number; if they are, you can make this markedly shorter.)*

But if it were me, I'd fade rather than just suddenly going to `opacity: 0` / `opacity: 1`: [Live Example](http://jsbin.com/naqesucu/2)

```
(function() {
    var bg = [
        "resources/images/bg/1.jpg",
        "resources/images/bg/2.jpg",
        "resources/images/bg/3.jpg",
        "resources/images/bg/4.jpg",
        "resources/images/bg/5.jpg",
        "resources/images/bg/6.jpg",
        "resources/images/bg/7.jpg",
        "resources/images/bg/8.jpg",
        "resources/images/bg/9.jpg",
        "resources/images/bg/10.jpg"
        ];
  var bgIndex = -1;
  setInterval(fadeBg, 10000);

  function fadeBg() {
    bgIndex = (bgIndex + 1) % bg.length;
    $('#bg').fadeTo("300", 0, showBg);
  }
  function showBg() {
    $('#bg').attr('src', bg[bgIndex]).fadeTo("300", 1);
  }
})();
```

Comment: `buildTheCallBack` should be inside quotes or anonymous function right?

Comment: OP is calling `fadebg` once each ten seconds, i don't think there is a  closure issue here, timeout callback should be called before recalling `fadebg`. Am I wrong?! But for sure better would be to use a closure

Comment: @A.Wolff: The issue is updating `i` within `fadeBg` and then using it 300ms later (in the subordinate `setTimeout` functions).

Comment: can you post the code with buildTheCallback function?

Comment: @AmitJoki: No, its job is to build the callback, immediately, so we *call* it and pass its return value (the function to call after 300ms) into `setTimeout`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, yeah. I know, that it will eval it, but I just said the options available.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I guess because too many people are taking examples from the MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536753(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @AmitJoki: No, no `eval` involved. What `buildTheCallback` builds **is** a function, not a string defining a function. Functions are first-class objects in JavaScript. Wrapping the function in another function (or worse, a string) is completely unnecessary.

Comment: @A.Wolff: LOL **ugh** MSDN, when it comes to web stuff, is only one step ahead of w3schools. Er, maybe...

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, I meant to say, you could write `setTimeout('buildTheCallback(args)',ms)` or `setTimeout(function(){ buildTheCallback(args)},ms);` and not `setTimeout(buildTheCallback(args),ms);`

Comment: @A.Wolff, See my above comment to know what I meant ;)

Comment: @AmitJoki: Right, but there's exactly zero reason to do that. The whole point of `buildTheCallback` is to build the callback.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, I commented that before your revisions. See your first [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/23660070/1). In that you've put `setTimeout(buildTheCallback(bg[i]), 300);`. Its okay, let's forget it.

Comment: @AmitJoki: Yes, that's still in the answer, and it's correct *without* any wrapper. `setTimeout(buildTheCallback(bg[i]), 300);` *calls* `buildTheCallback` with `bg[i]`. `buildTheCallback` creates and returns a new function that closes over the `src` argument we gave `buildTheCallback`. That's the function that goes to `setTimeout`. There is zero reason to wrap it. At best, wrapping it creates an unnecessary extra level of indirection. At worst, it reintroduces the problem `buildTheCallback` is there to solve.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, ah! Forgot that `buildTheCallback` is actually returning a function. Sorry `:)`

Comment: @AmitJoki: No worries. :-) Let's clean up these comments, since they don't add anything.

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
function fadebg() {
    if( i == 10 ){
      i = -1;
    }
    $('#bg').css({ opacity: 0 });
    setTimeout(function () {
      $('#bg').attr('src', bg[i]).css({ opacity: 1 })
    }, 300);
    i++;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to do something like this to make your function smaller:

```
bg.each(function(i){
    $('#bg').css({opacity:0});
    setTimeout(function () {
        $('#bg').attr('src', bg[i]).css({ opacity: 1 })
    }, 300);
});
```

I haven't tested that yet, but it might be something to look into.